# How to retrieve element of an array which are at every Xth position?

Tags: c#, arrays

In C# 4.0, is there a way to extract every element of a double[] into another array if the position of the `element + k` is a multiple of `n` ? i.e. if `k` is `3` and `n` is `4`, I want to create an array `a2` from the array `a1` with the 3rd, 7th, 11th ... positions (so in C# since arrays start at `0`, it would be `a1[2]`, `a1[6]`, `a1[10]` ... etc)

I am interested in having the fastest way to achieve this in terms of performance in C# and I know how to do this using a for loop.

Comment: This is something that I certainly would use a `for` loop for. I'm not sure what the point of this exercise is but I'm sure there's nothing built-in to do this.

Comment: Why would you *expect* anything to be faster than using a loop? It's not like this is a particularly common operation...

Comment: You can use Where LINQ method.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was really wondering if someone put a builtin functionality in the framework to speed up this kind of functionality. Since Jon Skeet says that there is no such thing, I guess it answers my question :)

Comment: @OndraMorský: what would be the syntax of the Where request for this one ?

Comment: Here are some method details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx. You have to use where method with (index, item) parameter and based on index return true(include in result) or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a faster way than using a for-loop. Anyway it might be possible using `Linq` operations on `IEnumerable` like [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb549418.aspx):

```
double[] doubleArray = {10.0,3.0,5.0,6.0};
IEnumerable<double> = doubleList.Where((number,index) => number + index % n == 0 );
```

I'm not sure I have understood the condition you want to satisfy. Anyway substitute the anonymous method body with the desired one.

Comment: Why do you explicitly do ToList()?

Comment: @LightStriker: thanks...I didn't know array already implemented IEnumerable.

Comment: I think what he means is `(index - k) % n == 0`